# What's the difference between "a year", "per year" and "out of a year"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, syntactic-analysis, particles

Suppose I want to say that I'm at sea seven months out of twelve. (Just an example.)

I think I can say

> "I'm at sea 7 months *a year*"

or

> "I'm at sea 7 months *per year*"

or

> "I'm at sea 7 months *out of a year*"

and in all three cases I would be correct. (Again, I *think*, feel free to correct me!) But what's the difference? And which one would be the more appropriate?

Comment: Actually, all three are incorrect, as you wanted to say you're at sea eight months out of twelve, not seven :-)
Ignoring that silly mistake, the first two are the same, IMO, although "per year" sounds more formal than "a year".  Even more formal would be "per annum".
"out of a year" feels a bit odd to me, and I would avoid it.  It could be changed to "7 months out of 12", and that would be fine.

Comment: I agree largely with @PhilMJones, but would add that all 3 options are slightly ambiguous as to whether you are referring to a *calendar year* (Jan - Dec) or just to any 12-month period. Personally I think "a year" is *most* likely to be understood as meaning any 12-month period, whereas the 'more formal' "per year" and "out of a year" are more likely to imply a calendar year.  Of course, as Phil suggested, you could just say "7 months out of 12".

Comment: I am curious: why not make these responses as answers instead of comments?  I think you answer the question perfectly: all three are basically equivalent, with the only additional necessary information being whether it's 7 months out of any 12-month period or out of a calendar year.

Comment: @PhilMJones Fixed! _Out of a year_ feels odd to me as well, but I've seen this expression more than once (although not often), so I included it.

Answer (score 3):

7 months a year means 7 months for each/every year.

"Per" in English is used to mean "for each". Therefore 7 months per year = 7 months for each year.

7 months out of a year just comes across as a clumsy way of saying it.